Error " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`" al migrar a Jetpack
Siguiendo la aplicación de ejemplo Now In Android estoy migrando mi código a Jetpack Compose.
Al abrir la aplicación, la misma termina con el siguiente error fatal:
             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
                 at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:89)
                 at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
                 at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:170)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:69)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt__ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:162)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(Unknown Source:1)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt__ViewModel_androidKt.viewModel(ViewModel.android.kt:124)
                 at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(Unknown Source:1)
                 at org.deiverbum.app.feature.foryou.ForYouScreenKt.ForYouRoute(ForYouScreen.kt:617)
                 at org.deiverbum.app.feature.foryou.navigation.ForYouNavigationKt$forYouScreen$3.invoke(ForYouNavigation.kt:30)
                 at org.deiverbum.app.feature.foryou.navigation.ForYouNavigationKt$forYouScreen$3.invoke(ForYouNavigation.kt:29)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
                 at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:295)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                 at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:803)
                 at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:792)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
                 at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)

El problema ocurre al intentar cargar el ViewModel en esta parte, pues los puntos de interrupción llegan bien hasta ahí:
@Composable
internal fun ForYouRoute(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ForYouViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val onboardingUiState by viewModel.onboardingUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val feedState by viewModel.feedState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val isSyncing by viewModel.isSyncing.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val deepLinkedUserNewsResource by viewModel.deepLinkedNewsResource.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    //
}

En el archivo gradle estas son las dependencias que tengo y que podrían ser relativas a este error:
// Hilt
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.2.0'
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.2.0"

// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.7"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.0"

He intentado varias soluciones, como agregar ciertas dependencias según se sugiere en este hilo de Github o en esta pregunta, pero el problema persiste.
Cabe decir que mi aplicación actual no es multi modular, como lo es la aplicación más arriba referida, por si esto tuviera que ver con el error.
¿Alguna idea sobre cómo resolver este error?

Tengo ese error y ni siquiera estoy usando Jetpack, a ver si lo resuelvo y te cuento.
